# Session login sample cannot open facebook login page in browser on the phone

Tags: android, facebook, intellij-idea

I am using Facebook android SDK 3.0 (quite new to it), and running the sample `SessionLoginSample` located in the sample directory of the downloaded SDK. The target is to test if the session login sample can trigger the browser and lead user to the Facebook login page without the Facebook for Android application installed. No luck, the `SessionLoginSample` force closed.
However, if the Facebook for Android app installed, the user could be lead to the login activity of the app. Enter the account/password then go back the `SessionLoginSample` without any issue. It **looks like the Session object won't trigger browser and lead user to Facebook login page?**

**Edit:** append the log

```
02-10 15:35:46.180: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050012
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050012
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:260)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:344)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:282)
    at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(WebDialog.java:188)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:461)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:209)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:188)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:116)
    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:97)
    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:113)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1157)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4544)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445)
    ... 12 more
```

---

**Solve the original problem:**
Just found the `strings.xml` file in the values folder in the res folder of Facebook android SDK has been changed! The `WebDialog` works without problem after copy the string items back. Quite weird, I NEVER change that file manually. I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 12` as the IDE to build and run my project. Might be this problem caused by `IntelliJ IDEA`??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any debug log you can share ? It's quite possible that something hasn't built properly as I have run the app without having a facebook app installed on my device. The app shows a loginButton which triggers the login dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it work after check the output message from logcat.